# Knockout Create Temporary Variable inside foreach

Tags: knockout.js

How create temporary variable inside foreach loop...

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: question, as: 'question' }-->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: question.answers, as: 'answer' }-->

    // i want to define temporary variable here like:

    var answer_name = answer.name;

    if($parents[1].lang){
        answer_name = answer[$parents[1].lang + '_name'];
    }

    <span data-bind="text: answer_name">
    // How to do like this?    
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I don't want to use computed values and observables it's JS objects.

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to use computed values?  Not doing so means you're attempting to mix logic back into your views, when the proper place for it is in your viewmodel, using computeds.

Answer (score 0):

### Real answer

Make viewmodels with computed properties, even though you don't want to.

### Other answer, to show you why you should pick the *real answer*

The only way to modify your data in your view, is to write a custom binding, or find a hacky way to execute code in a regular binding. For example, if you don't want to make viewmodels for your plain objects, you'll need to put the computed logic in the `foreach` binding. (very ugly!)

In the example below I convert the `data` that `foreach` uses in an inline computed in the view. Within the computed, you have access to the binding context (`$context`) and everything that's in it (like `$parent`). All the stuff you want to do, (but shouldn't) is available.

- Access the `$parent` layer of each item (which, at this point, is just the data context)
- Add a new property (`word_translated`) to each item, based on information in this layer
- Use the new property in a binding inside the foreach: `item.word_translated`

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  translations: {
    en: {
      "tree": "tree",
      "house": "house"
    },
    nl: {
      "tree": "boom",
      "house": "huis"
    }
  },
  language: ko.observable("en"),
  languages: ["en", "nl"],

  words: [{
      index: 0,
      word: "house"
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      word: "tree"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
Language: <select data-bind="options: languages, value: language">
</select>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: ko.computed(function() {
  return words.map(function(item) {
    return Object.assign({}, item, { 
      word_translated: translations[language()][item.word]
    })
  })
}), as: 'item' }">
  <li>
    <strong data-bind="text: item.index +': '"></strong>
    <span data-bind="text: item.word_translated"></span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your looking for:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: question, as: 'question' }-->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: question.answers, as: 'answer' }-->
    <span data-bind="text: $parent[1].lang ? answer[$parent[1].lang + '_name'] : answer.name">
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can use literal name inside the child scope:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: question, as: 'question' }-->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: question.answers, as: 'answer' }-->
    <span data-bind="text: question.lang ? answer[question.lang + '_name'] : answer.name">
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

And IMO this code better to move into the function inside the `answer` object:

```
function getLocalizedText(question) {
    return question.lang ? this[question.lang + '_name'] : this.name;
}
```

So markup will looks like

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: question, as: 'question' }-->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: question.answers, as: 'answer' }-->
    <span data-bind="text: answer.getLocalizedText(question)">
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```